# Custom factorial function not working as expected

Tags: c++

Here is a simple factorial calculator. I have called the function `factorial` with three different arguments to test it. For some reason, the function is not returning the expected values:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int factorial(int a) {
  int result = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    result *= result + 1;
  }
  return result;
}

int main() {
  cout << factorial(4) << endl; // returns 1806, expected 24
  cout << factorial(5) << endl; // returns 3263442, expected 120
  cout << factorial(6) << endl; // returns -1461943274, expected 720
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the definition of factorial? Apparently, you aren't so familiar with it.

Comment: Maybe you could try to write on paper what your program does for some of your inputs. (Not necessarily paper, the point is to go step by step by yourself as your program would)

Comment: And use your debugger.  It's quicker than posting here.

Comment: Step through the program with a debugger so that you can see what each step is doing. `result *= result + 1;` should be `result *= i + 1;`

Comment: It is not necessary to define factorial() before using it.

Comment: @WaisKamal, how are you supposed to implement some algorithm if you aren't sure how it works?? I meant the definition in maths, not in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your factorial function, you are adding 1 why ? You should start your loop from `i=1` to `i<=a` and multiply `i` instead of `+1`,

By mathematics definition `Factorial of n = n*(n-1)*(n-2)...3.2.1`

You can modify your code like this

```
int factorial(int a) {
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <=a; i++) {
        result = result * i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or you can use recursive function

```
int factorial(int a) {
    if (a == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return a * factorial(a - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a while loop in your function instead of a for loop:

```
int factorial(int a) 
{
   int result = 1;
   while (a > 0)
   {
      result *= a;
      a--;
    }
  return result;
 }
```

Edit:
One issue with your code is that you are not decreasing i in your for loop: It should be like this:

```
 int factorial(int a) {
   int result = 1;
   for (int i = a; i > 0; i--)
   }
    result *= i;
   return result;
 }
```